# From odbc sql connection in MATLAB to write data.csv

Tags: sql-server, matlab, csv, indexing, printf

I currently look for advice on a tedious task:

**1/ looping into date column from sql query such as:**

Current code:

```
clc;clearvars;
%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');

% Set maximum time allowed for establishing a connection.
timeout=logintimeout(10);

%Make connection to database.  Note that the password has been omitted.
%Using ODBC driver.
conn = database('odbccalc', 'xxxx', 'xxx');

% Check the database status.
ping(conn);

% Select time series data from database.
startdate=num2str('2003-03-03');
enddate=num2str('2015-06-08');

sql=['select d.Date, d.Px_last from tblData d '...
  'where d.ISN = ' '''DMIXUSD'''...
  'and d.Date between (''',startdate,''') and (''',enddate,''')'...
  'order by d.Date desc'];

curs=exec(conn,sql);
curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable
dmix = curs.Data;

%Convert cells array to vector of Double
vecpx=cell2mat(dmix(:,2));

%Close database connection.
close(conn);

%Clear variables
clear curs conn;

% Compute return vector and carry other calculations that work from my side as:

nrow=length(vecpx);
 for i=1:nrow-1
 vretx(i)=log(vecpx(i)/vecpx(i+1));
 end
tretx=vretx.';
     ....
 val1=.....
 val7=....
```

*So far all is fine* so, but the challenge or aim now consists of finding a way to achieve:

**a/**

```
daily = cellstr(dmix(:,1)); % not sure it's the right command
```

**b/**  **Indexing** through dates and **looping** such as

```
for k =daily(1) : daily(end) - 1000
indvretx(k)=log(vecpx(k)/vecpx(k+1));
indtretx=vretx.';
     ....
 indval1=.....
 indval7=....
end
```

**c/** **Output** to screen each date from **startdate** until **enddate** the results and export it to csv:

```
a=[indval1 indval2 indval3 indval4 indval5 indval6 indval7]; 
fprintf( '%6s %6s %12s %12s %6s %12s %12s %12s\n','Date' 'norm',  'whs', 
       'stbl','normes', 'whes', 'stbles', 'ret');
fprintf('%6s  %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f  %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f 
       %12.8f\n',daily, a.',indtretx);
```

This will prevent me from copying and pasting manually on Excel more than 3000 results. So the gain in time is **incommensurable!!**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: as I've eventually found way arounds:

**a/** used daily as cell array

```
= dmx(:,1) %so as to get an array of dates
```

**b/** used **while loop** after defining

```
i=1;
data=Rt(i:end,1);
```

**c/** pending...Thinking of a way to use **fprint()** on both cell array and double data types